# How to add button inside dc.js table?

Tags: dc.js

How do I add a button with event listener in dc.js data table in a new column.

I basically want to add custom html if possible.

Comment: Have you tried returning HTML from the [column formatting functions](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html#columns). If so, what didn’t work?

Comment: See [this comment](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/534#issuecomment-342952112) for how to add event handlers for clicks on cells. Pretty much the same thing but you’d make the selector more specific so it’s attached to the buttons. Happy to work up an example if you can’t figure it out!

Comment: Will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the button is simply a matter of returning the html for the column for

```
dc.dataTable (dom)
.columns ([function (d) { return "<button>Clickedy click</button>" }])
.on('renderlet', function (graph) {
  graph.selectAll('button')
  .on('click.clickedy',function(d){
    console.log(d);
   })
```

'renderlet' or 'pretransition' for the event, don't think it matters much in this case